# marker size uniform in d3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

i am creating marker on my force directed graph. in my force directed graph i have lines or links of different thickness or stroke. because of this the markers are getting created with different sizes. what i want is to have uniform size of marker.
here is my code for marker :

```
 `svg.append('defs').append('svg:marker')
  .classed("arrowhead",true)
  .attr('id', 'arrowhead')              
  .attr('viewBox', '0 -5 40 40')
  .attr('refX', "25")
  .attr('markerWidth', 8)
  .attr('markerHeight', 8)
   .attr('orient', 'auto')
   .append('svg:path')
  .attr('d', 'M0,-5L10,0L0,5')
  .attr('fill', 'black');`
```

how can i have marker with uniform size??
thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you tried setting the stroke width on the marker definition?

Comment: In what way isn't it uniform? There's only one path in your example so how can it be different, there's nothing for it to be different from.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent a SVG marker (arrow head) to inherit path's stroke width?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626748/how-to-prevent-a-svg-marker-arrow-head-to-inherit-paths-stroke-width)

Answer (score 1):

By default markers are relative to the stroke-width (see [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#MarkerUnitsAttribute)), but you can set `markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` on the marker element to make the marker size not be relative to the stroke-width.

To clarify, this doesn't make the marker size static and the same for all elements using the marker. The rendered marker is still subject to the transform set on the elements that use the marker. But it does make the size be independent of the stroke-width.

Comment: how did you implement markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" in your marker definition. I am new to d3, i need to apply same for my marker too.

i have applied in this way:
svg.append('defs').append('svg:marker')
.classed("arrowhead",true)             .attr('id', 'arrowhead')             .attr('viewBox', '0 -5 40 40')             .attr('refX', "26")             .attr('markerWidth', 8)             .attr('markerHeight', 8)             .attr('orient', 'auto')
.append('svg:path')
.attr('d', 'M0,-5L10,0L0,5')         .attr('fill', 'black')       .attr('markerUnits','userSpaceOnUse');

But it dint work for me

Comment: @erik-dahlström: so does this mean that there's no way you can have markers that can be uniform size? I'm experiencing the same problem and I added the attribute of `makersUnits` you mentioned, but I still see that the marker sizes' are changing. Any way to prevent this?